# What does "discipline" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

First of all, I've always had a problem with the word *discipline* as I translated it to my language many times, but without understanding its real meaning.

Now I have this text:

> If you were to fault yourself in one of three areas, which would it be: (1) the inability to prioritize; (2) the inability or desire to organize around those priorities; or (3) the lack of **discipline** to execute around them, to stay with your priorities and organizations?

Please, what does *discipline* mean? I can't understand that sentence without it.

Comment: Will power or strength of character to act on and follow the principles you say you believe in.

Comment: And what language is that?

Answer (score 1):

> #### Discipline
>
> 1. Training that corrects, molds, or perfects the mental faculties or moral character.
> 2. Self-control

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discipline))

In this context, I believe the statement

> *the lack of discipline to execute around them, to stay with your priorities and organizations*

is referencing the concept that one lacks the self-control or training required to stick by one's priorities and organizations.

So, one is able to prioritize and organize those priorities, but is does not possess enough self-control or will-power required to stay with them.

Comment: Or maybe "_willpower_ ", which is very close to "_self control_ " anyway.
Sorry Yosef Baskin, I missed your comment! You said it first but this comment, once started, seems indelible.

Comment: @Chiron I like willpower as another view of it.

Comment: This question is more suitable for ELL (if indeed it is not general reference).

Comment: I think the OP knows the definition of the word, but lacks the simple understanding of it's meaning used in the example. While it may end up being a ELL issue, I don't think it necessarily has to be migrated.

Comment: I got in trouble here at ELU at some point for answering questions that were not well posed.  I was scolded, in fact, and not very nicely.  I will try not to do the same.  The problem with this question is that the OP didn't show what research she had done, and didn't explain what she was confused about.  When this happens, the preference here on ELU is that the OP be asked via a comment to improve the question -- before providing an answer.  (Some OPs wander off and don't improve the question.)  For more info, see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9761/112436.

Comment: @aparente001 While I do agree, I think there is a grey area.I do not answer questions with little to no content in them or ones lacking multiple concepts (context, research, etc), but I do feel like some are acceptable to answer without every single box being checked. I used to think the same way as you, but I've come to realize it isn't black and white. While the OP does not show specific research, I get the idea that the basic definition is known, but the understanding is still missing. That is why I answered and I do stand by it.

Comment: *"I used to think the same way as you"*....  Who, me?  I'm trying to explain how things work in Rome ("When in Rome..."), because the way things were explained to me was painful. I personally don't care much.  I just wanted to warn you.

Comment: @aparente001 I do appreciate the warning. I have asked my own meta question before about this and have learnt the above comment. I do appreciate the heads up, though! Sorry the original explanation to you was painful :/